# Android grid layout align like GridLayoutManager style

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I have the following GridLayout which stores a number of 6 maximum columns :

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/pokemonTeambuilderSpritesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:columnCount="6"
        app:rowCount="1"
        app:useDefaultMargins="true" />
```

And here I populate it :

```
  List<Pokemon> pokemonList = pokemonTeam.getPokemonList();
    for (Pokemon pokemon : pokemonList) {
        CircularImageView ivPokemonSprite = new CircularImageView(mContext);
        String pokemonId = pokemon.get_id();
        int pokemonImageId = PokemonUtils.getPokemonSugimoriImageById(pokemonId, mContext);
        Picasso.get().load(pokemonImageId).into(ivPokemonSprite);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f),
                GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1f)
        );
        layoutParams.width = 0;
        ivPokemonSprite.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        holder.teamSpritesGridLayout.addView(ivPokemonSprite);

    }
```

My current output with 6 images is this :

[image]

With 3 images :

[image]

With 2 images:

[image]

My desired output would be :

For 6 images:

[image]

For 2 images:

[image]

For 4 images:

[image]

I want it to add them starting from left to right uniform and If the image doesn't have enough space to fit on its own I want it to "collide" with the others instead of letting margin between them (as you can see in the examples). Thats how I see that the GridLayoutManager works . How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom layout for handling your different cases. something like below:

```
 public class PokemonLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int childWidth;

    public PokemonLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public PokemonLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PokemonLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public PokemonLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        childWidth = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            height = Math.max(child.getMeasuredHeight(), height);
            childWidth = Math.max(child.getMeasuredWidth(), childWidth);
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int leftParent, int topParent, int rightParent, int bottomParent) {
        int count = getChildCount();
        boolean overlap = count * childWidth > width;
        int widthOffset = childWidth;
        if(overlap) {
            widthOffset = childWidth - (Math.abs(width - (count * childWidth)) / (count-1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = (View) getChildAt(i);
            child.layout(i*widthOffset,
                    0,(i*widthOffset) + childWidth
                    , child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

For 3 images:

[image]

For 5 images:

[image]

UPDATE 1:
change onLayout method to positioning children at the center of layout

```
   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int leftParent, int topParent, int rightParent, int bottomParent) {
       int count = getChildCount();
       boolean overlap = count * childWidth > width;
       int widthOffset = childWidth;
       int startOffest = (width - (count * childWidth)) / 2;

       if(overlap) {
           startOffest = 0;
           widthOffset = childWidth - (Math.abs(width - (count * childWidth)) / (count-1));
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
           View child = (View) getChildAt(i);
           child.layout(startOffest+ (i*widthOffset),
                   0,(i*widthOffset) + childWidth + startOffest
                   , child.getMeasuredHeight());
       }
   }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm , impressive!

Comment: Extra question :how can I make this layout to center the elements of each row?

Comment: you should do some calculation, e.g. calculate 3 items' width, minus it from width of layout, and divide result into 2. then use this result as a offset for layouting children on FrameLayout.   child.layout(offset + (i*widthOffset), .....      if overlap is true, offset should be zero

Comment: I do not understand english very well , can you edit you answer please :) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate , I would acept this answer twice if I could haha

Comment: can you please add to the answer the example snippet of your color squares and how did you added them to the layout?

Comment: @NexussimLements
You can use PokemonLayout in your XML and then put multiple ImageViews with different Background or images as its children